# How to modify these distances in moderncv?

Tags: spacing, moderncv

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\firstname{\Huge{Manuel}}
\familyname{Dopazo Souto}
\title{\Large{Carpinteiro\newline{}\newline{}Wood worker}}
\address{Rúa dabaixo}{36.000, Pontevedra}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{649.45.74.35}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%MICHI%\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{carpinteiro@carpinteiros.com}
\extrainfo{Data de nacemento: 2 de Xaneiro de 1.492}
\photo[60pt]{example-image-a.jpg}
\nopagenumbers{}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm, bottom=1.25cm,right=1.61cm, left=1.61cm}% inner=1cm, outer=0.618\textwidth
\vspace*{-0.56cm}
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\vspace*{-1.24cm}
\vspace*{-0.18cm}

\section{Formación Académica}
\cventry{2015}{Carpinteria de arriba.}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Up's wood factory.}}{}{}{}
\cventry{2009--2014}{Carpinteria de abaixo}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Down wood factory. Galicia.}}{}{}{}

\section{Experiencia}
\cventry{2015}{Carpinteria de arriba.}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Up's wood factory.}}{}{}{}




\end{document}
%% end of file `template_en.tex'.
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the first ones, the option is simply: vspace{}

```
\firstname{\Huge{Xan}}
\familyname{Do Campo\vspace{-0.24cm}}
\title{\Large{Craftman\newline{}\vspace{-0.24cm}\newline{}Wood}}
```

To modify the other distances?

Answer (score 1):

Some generic suggestions:

- Instead of using `\firstname{\Huge{..}}`, redefine `\namefont`:

  ```
  \renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge}
  ```

  Note also that `\Huge` is a font *switch*, not a macro, so the usage would typically be `{\Huge ..}` rather than `\Huge{..}`.
- Similarly, update `\titlefont` instead of setting the title font in the title:

  ```
  \renewcommand{\titlefont}{\Large}
  ```
- For the red spaces:

  - Update the `\namestyle` macro which sets the name. You can append a `\vspace` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) (already loaded by [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)):

    ```
    \apptocmd{\namestyle}{<len>}{}{}
    ```
  - The gap between the `\title` entries can be obtained using `\\[<len>]`. However, since the `\title` also ends up as part of the PDF properties (since [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is at play), warnings will be issued if used as-is. So, instead do

    ```
    \title{Carpinteiro \texorpdfstring{\\[<len>]}{/} Wood worker}
    ```

    This should help TeX discern between content supposed to be set in the resulting PDF, or as part of the PDF properties. Within the latter, a `/` will separate `Carpinteiro` from `Wood worker`.
- For the green spaces:

  These are set between `\section`s. So let's see what the `\section` macro looks like under your `\moderncvstyle`; [`moderncvbodyi.sty`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvbodyi.sty):

  ```
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
    \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
    \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
    \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color1}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
    \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
  ```

  Every `\section` is started by `add`ing some `v`ertical `space` up to `2.5ex`. You can change this value to suit your by copying the above redefinition and updating the length `2.5ex` (placing `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` around your new redefinition).
- For the purple/pink spaces:

  These spaces are also inserted by the `\section` command. Specifically, the last `\addvspace` that inserts `1ex`. Change this to suit your needs as well, together with the above redefinition.